# Fetch Request Body from org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserter

Tags: spring, logging, request, reactive-programming, webclient

I have the below code where I am able to log the headers and URL. But the body() method is returning an object of type BodyInserter. In the debug mode(STS), we can see the request body object. Is there any way to log the request?

```
[private ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {         loggingService.info(clientRequest.url());
            loggingService.info(clientRequest.headers()); 

            BodyInserter<?, ? super ClientHttpRequest> bodyInserters= clientRequest.body();
            return Mono.just(clientRequest);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this @nikhil?